# Hide checkbox/div based on textbox value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown, when i select an item its categoryId is assigned to textbox. Then i Have 2 checkboxes 'IsAnonymous' and 'ShowReport'. I want to implement that is the value in textbox is 1 then both checkbox will be visible and when value will be 2 then 'ShowReport' checkbox must be hidden.

```
javascript
var ReportDiv = $('#ReportDiv');
$('#cmbCategories').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '1') {
        ReportDiv.hide();
    }
    else {

        ReportDiv.show();
    }
});
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.PollSurveyId, Model.PollSurveyDetails, "Select Poll/Survey", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", @id= "DDPollName" })
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(p => p.CategoryID, new {id= "cmbCategories" })
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.Label("Is Anonymous")
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.IsAnonymous)
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="form-group" id="ReportDiv">
                                @Html.Label("Show Report")
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.ShowReport, new { id= "CBReport" })



                            </div>
                            <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
                        </div>
```

[Added a picture to give idea of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I08yI.png)

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: Not working. Whether the value in textbox is 1 or 2, showreport checkbox is visible all the time @StephenMuecke

Comment: Type the value in the textbox and it will work. The `.change()` event is not triggered if its being set using javascript. Handle the `.change()` event of your dropdownlist instead - i.e. `$('#DDPollName').change(function() { ...hide/show });` (its not even clear why you have the textbox)

Comment: textbox is just to show the categoryId, if for the selected name from dropdown the textbox value is 1 then its poll and if 2 then its survey. I can't pass the value directly to textbox. @StephenMuecke

Comment: Did you not read my previous comment? Handle the `.change()` event of the dropdownlist! Your textbox is pointless - remove it.

Comment: I had this feeling that this .change() event must be for dropdown that's i put this question here to get to know the event for textbox value change. @StephenMuecke

Comment: My moto is just to hide ShowReport checkbox when categoryId is 1, that's why i took textbox which i'm gonna hide by the way. @StephenMuecke

Comment: .change is working on my test but it seems like returning int value not char so when you change if ($(this).val() == '1') this to this if ($(this).val() == 1) its working at least for me.

Comment: Don't hide the textbox - DELETE IT! Its pointless

Comment: @ReadyFreddy not working just tried. :/

Comment: @StephenMuecke and how must i achieve my requirement can u tell me?

Comment: I have already told you - `$('#DDPollName').change(function() { if ($(this).val() == 1) { ReportDiv.hide(); } else { ReportDiv.show(); }});`

Comment: Now i understand what Stephen said and it's true...

Comment: if you want to detect change on text box use
$('#cmbCategories').on('input', function () {})

Comment: Just to make sure is it like hiding ReportDive based on index changed in DropDown. Because i have 50 name in DropDown which belong to either 'Poll(CategoryId=1)' or 'Survey(CategoryId=2)'. And just as i told before for 'CategoryId=1' 'ReportDiv' must b hidden @ReadyFreddy

Comment: @StephenMuecke is it??